# Keycloak with streamlit returns an empty token in the first time

Tags: keycloak, streamlit

I use the library streamlit_keycloak to authenticate a streamlit application with Keycloak. But each time, when I'm logged in, I get the token in 2 times : an empty one then the full one.

Is it asynchronous ?

How can I get the right token right away ? or wait for the right token ?

**Empty token :**
Keycloak(authenticated=False, access_token=None, refresh_token=None, user_info=None, id_token=None)

**Full token :**
Keycloak(authenticated=True, access_token='eyJ...' ...)

The issue is that the app displays a wrong page with the empty token, then 1 second later, it refreshes and display the right content.

```
my_keycloak = login(
        url=config.URL,
        realm=config.REALM,
        client_id=config.CLIENT_ID,
        init_options={
            "checkLoginIframe": False
        }
    )

if my_keycloak.authenticated:
    st.write("Authenticated")
else:
    st.write("Not authenticated")
```

So I get as display (when I'm logged in):

Not authenticated

Authenticated

How can I have only one display "Authenticated" ?